# Where can I find a catalogue or lists of realtime, streaming (major) airport cameras?

Tags: airport, website, plane-spotting

I ask in the spirit of aircraft spotting and would also prefer those with live ATC feeds, like [Osaka](http://www.webcamhopper.com/ust/itami.html). As of now, the visual quality is blurry and hazy, but perhaps this is due to low visibility and bad weather?

On the side panel of that, I clicked on another for [Narita](http://www.webcamhopper.com/ust/narita.html), but this one doesn't capture the (active) runways.

Is there an efficacious, systematic method to find all such webcams for substantive airports worldwide? Do such manifests or records already exist? I tried [a forum thread](http://forum.flightradar24.com/threads/352-Planespotting-All-Live-Airport-Video-Webcam/page3) on FlightRadar24 which cites [airportwebcams.net](http://airportwebcams.net), but these are NOT streaming and realtime.

Comment: what about google? ...

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a website link with a list, but we can create a collaborative Community Wiki with all the webcams everyone knows — feel free to edit this answer to add any you know!

---

### Americas

#### Brazil

- [FLN/SBFL - Hercílio Luz/Florianopolis](http://www.vejoaovivo.com.br/sc/florianopolis/aeroporto-hercilio-Luz.html)
- [NVT/SBNF - Navegantes](http://www.vejoaovivo.com.br/sc/navegantes/aeroporto-de-navegantes.html)

#### Canada

- [NavCanada Weather Webcams](http://www.metcam.navcanada.ca/lb/index.jsp?lang=e&ui=lb) (only available at some airports, updated every 10 minutes)

#### Chile

- [All airports and aerodromes](http://www.aipchile.gob.cl/camara/)

---

### Europe

#### Germany

- [DUS/EDDL - Düsseldorf](http://www.dus.com/dus/webcams/)
- [CGN/EDDK - Cologne Bonn/Köln-Bonn](http://www.koeln-bonn-airport.de/en/airport/airport-webcam.html)